# Not able to get value from $routeParams

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am trying to get value I inserted in $routeParams and show it on the web page. Suppose if I do like my_url/hello I want hello to be printed on screen, but it shows following error. 
Cannot GET /app.html/hello

In console it shows this error 
GET 127.0.0.1:50655/app.html/hello 404 (Not Found)

Plunker link for code :: https://plnkr.co/edit/9uHJzycPyWi8M6ynSWkE?p=preview

This is my app.js file

```
var myApp=angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.when("/:message",
    {
      templateUrl: "app.html",
      controller: "myCtrl",
      controllerAs: "app"
    }
  );
})

.controller('myCtrl', function($routeParams) {
  var self = this;
  self.message = $routeParams.message;
});
```

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: try `27.0.0.1:50655/hello` you dont need app.html in the route

Comment: updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NOzUTZPTIwRV60rN05lL?p=preview) please check. here when you click on home it shows app.html.

Comment: no @harishr and it's not working..I tried http://127.0.0.1:63422/index.html/hello and http://127.0.0.1:63422/hello, but it's not working